# Finding matching columns in pandas including NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a quite specific question regarding `pandas`. I have two DataFrames, both are binary : One containing multiple patterns to match lets say :

```
0 : 1,NaN,1,Nan,Nan  
1 : Nan,1,1,Nan,Nan
```

and one containing records of actual data

```
0 : 1,0,0,1,0  
1 : 0,0,0,0,1  
2 : 1,0,1,0,0
```

I want to perform an operation that tells me which lines of the record data match which rules. In the example rule 0 would match record 2. The missing values don't have to match anything, and therein lies my problem : if there wouldn't be any missing values I could simply use `pd.merge(df1,df2,how="inner")`, but an inner join doesn't match `NaN`s with anything.

Is there a simple elegant solution without doing all the loops?

**Edit to add** (for clarity):

This:

```
0 : 1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

should match with **both** of these:

```
0 : 1,1,0,0,0
1 : 1,1,0,0,1
```

Comment: can you post what output you want to achieve?

Comment: The desired output would be a table with two rows : one with the row number of the matched record and one with the row number of the matched column. I want to know that record two matched with rules 1,2,3; record 15 matched with rules 1,2; I don't want to see any records that didn't match any rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is binary we can using `duplicated`

```
df=pd.concat([df1.fillna(0),df2],keys=['df1','df2'])
df[df.astype(int).duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[37]: 
         1    2  3    4    5
df1 0  1.0  0.0  1  0.0  0.0
df2 2  1.0  0.0  1  0.0  0.0
```

EDIT

```
dd=df1.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0').level_1.apply(list).tolist()
dd
Out[67]: [['1', '3'], ['2', '3']]

df2.apply(lambda x : sum([all(x.loc[y]==1) for y in dd]),1 )

Out[78]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
df2[df2.apply(lambda x : sum([all(x.loc[y]==1) for y in dd]),1 )==1]
Out[80]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
2  1  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: I like it with duplicated!

Comment: Would it match 1,1,Nan,Nan,Nan to  1,1,0,0,1 tho?

Comment: I think it has the same effect than the inner join since you fill in the NaNs with 0's. If the missing values is 0 then it is matched but I want to match it too even if the missing values are something else! Only the given Values have to correspond for the rule to match

Comment: @Blackliquid you can using mask :-)